# Preventing a Java class from being instantiated and inherited

Tags: java, inheritance, instance

I've been asked to modify a simple class so it would not be able to be instantiated and inherited.
I got confused on how to use abstract for not being instantiated and final for not being inherited.

How should I write such a class ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A class can't be both final and abstract. You can prevent instantiation by hiding the constructor, and raising an exception to prevent instantiation via reflection.

That looks like this:

```
final class MyClass {
    private MyClass() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot be instantiated"); //some exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// final can not be inherited
// only static methods will work on this class
final class FrozenClass {
  private FrozenClass() {
    // can not be instantiated
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For this reason you have to make your class final and add a private constructor:
look at this example:

```
final class  uninstantiable {
    private uninstantiable() {
    }
}
```

so now whenever you try to instantiate new object it will err **`classname` has private access in `packagename`**.